# Query in MySQL Father and son

Tags: mysql

I have a table to only I have 3 levels in structure example:

1 his son is 2 and 2 have a son is 4 and 6 
3 is father and his son is 5 
and 1 have a other son is 7 
4 doesn't have son because is a rule of the structure.

well my table is this:

> |Id_Father|   |Id_Son|
>              1               2 
>               2               4 
>              3               5 
>              2               6 
>              1               7

Only I want to bringme with my query every father to have one son, this is part of my query:

```
SELECT R.* FROM getName R where not EXISTS (SELECT 1 from Estructura R2 where R.id = R2.Id_Son) And  Exists (SELECT 1 from Estructura R2 where R.id = R2.Id_Father and  not exists (SELECT 1 from Estructura R3 where R2.Id_Son = R3.Id_Father ))
```

and I get this with my query :

> 1 and 3 but I want only get the 3.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
select id_father
from Estructura
group by id_father
having count(distinct id_son) = 1
```